# Is Browser Viewport Width Always Dependent Upon Windows 10 Scaling Setting?

Tags: windows, image, viewport, monitor

For websites being displayed on Chrome in Windows 10 v1909, does the website's viewport width **always** vary based upon the value of Windows 10's Scaling and Layout setting (found in Settings>Display>Scaling and Layout) when the viewport meta tag's `width` value is set to `device-width`?

I just bought a new 3840 x 2160 4K Ultra High Definition (UHD) monitor **thinking that the websites I design would be displayed at 3840 pixels wide.**  But when I inspected header elements using Chrome's Developer Tools, **the width of the viewport gets smaller as I scale Windows 10 higher.**  And because I can't read the text for anything displayed on this 4K UHD monitor at 3840 pixels wide (which happens when Windows 10 scaling is set to 100%), I have increased Windows 10 scaling to 175% so that I can read the text **comfortably.**  But when I increase the Windows 10 scaling, the viewport width of my browser shrinks in size (e.g., at 175% Windows 10 scaling the width of my browser viewport is 2195 pixels).  I did some experimentation and here are the widths of the browser viewport that are associated with specific Windows 10 scaling values:

- 100% scaling ... 3840 viewport width
- 125% scaling ... 3072 viewport width
- 150% scaling ... 2560 viewport width
- 175% scaling ... 2195 viewport width
- 200% scaling ... 1920 viewport width

The reason I posted this question is so that I can understand what size I need to make my images when desiging for 4K websites.  I use the Avada WordPress theme to design all of my client websites.  Their advice for desiging 4K websites is:

*"As a general rule, we currently use images that are 2000px wide for our demos which is usually big enough to make images look great on all common screen sizes."*

Looking at the table of Windows 10 scaling and browser viewport values listed above, it appears that Avada's image width advice applies to 4K UHD monitors **ONLY** when Windows 10 is scaled at 175% or higher (with a slight upsampling of the image occurring at 175% scaling).  Since scaling Windows 10 on a 4K UHD monitor at 150% is "iffy" in terms of being able to comfortably read text, and any scaling less than 150% is basically unreadable, it appears that a general rule of thumb for image width on 4K UHD monitors is 2600 pixels.  This image width would cover Windows 10 scaling at 150% and higher.

For Windows scaling less than 150%, a 2600 pixel image would be upsampled to fill the width of the viewport.  **However, it seems to me that most people will scale Windows 10 on a 4K UHD monitor to at least 150% in order for text to be readable (this is the BIG assumption that I believe drives how wide my images should be).**  Since the viewport width associated with Windows 10 scaling of 150% is 2560 pixels, images that are created at 2600 pixels wide would fill the browser viewport without upsampling (and possible loss of quality).

Am I understanding the relationship between Windows 10 scaling and browser viewport width correctly?  Is my conclusion about sizing all images for 4K website design at 2600 pixels width correct?